# oAuth2 Man in the middle attack protect?

Tags: security, mobile, oauth-2.0

How oAuth2 protect from MITM Attack.. how we can from access token validate if request messages has been manipulated or not?
Is sender deviceID and IP is part from oAuth2 Access token generation?

Comment: This was asked on [StackExchange Security] (http://security.stackexchange.com/questions/110720/how-is-oauth2-secure-vs-man-in-the-middle-attacks). Would that answer your question?

Comment: Does this means that sender ip taken in consideration  when generating and validating access token ?